# adding controls to a container programmatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

I have made a user control that contains a panel and i want to add another control that i made to it. All of this i want it to be realised programmatically.

Actualy i wanted to create a Calandar, sizable columns, and cells.

I Want to add my cells to my columns. then add my columns to my Calendar object.

Here is the code i created for the momment..

Creating the columns:

```
Private Sub CreateColumns()
    For i = 0 To Calendar.GetUpperBound(0)
        ASFColumns(i) = New ASFcolumn
        With ASFColumns(i)
            .Width = 252
            .Visible = True
            .Left = 250 * i + i + 2
            .Top = 35
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(ASFColumns(i))
        'AddHandler Calendar(i, j).Click, AddressOf ClickOnCells
    Next
End Sub
```

Adding my cells to it

```
For i = 0 To Calendar.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j = 0 To Calendar.GetUpperBound(1)
            Calendar(i, j) = New ASFmultiTaskCell
            With Calendar(i, j)
                .Width = 250
                .Visible = True
                .Left = 250 * j + j + 2
                .Top = 33 * i + i + 70
                .BringToFront()
            End With
            'Me.Controls.Add(Calendar(i, j)) 
            ASFColumns(i).Controls.Add(Calendar(i, j))
            AddHandler Calendar(i, j).Click, AddressOf ClickOnCells
        Next
    Next
```

Thank you

Comment: can you elaborate on what problems you're running into?

Comment: when i add my cells to the container control (columns) they dont show up on the screen. I will post picture as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, so I assumed some things. I created Calendar as a 2d array of ASFmultiTaskCell, which is a user control. The follow code sucessfully add the user controls to either a Form or a Panel/Group Box. The event works too.

```
Dim Calendar(2, 3) As ASFmultiTaskCell

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 0 To Calendar.GetUpperBound(0)
            For j = 0 To Calendar.GetUpperBound(1)
                Calendar(i, j) = New ASFmultiTaskCell
                With Calendar(i, j)
                    .Width = 250
                    .Visible = True
                    .Left = 250 * j + j + 2
                    .Top = 33 * i + i + 70
                    .BringToFront()
                End With

                Me.Controls.Add(Calendar(i, j))
                GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Calendar(i, j))

                AddHandler Calendar(i, j).Click, AddressOf ClickOnCells
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClickOnCells()

    End Sub
```